# searching for element in a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary

```
{('22', '83', '75', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '22', '23', '24', '18', '14'): 1, 
 ('1', '2', '83', '5', '8', '75', '9', '12', '16', '17', '18', '14'): 1, 
 ('11', '2', '7', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '18', '14'): 1}
```

Its keys are tuples.

Now I need to search whether a pair of elements such as `(83,75)` exist in any of its keys and 
also I need to make sure that `83` and `75` are present in a given key in that order. 
So for in 1st key in the sample dictionary this is true but not for the second key.

I know I can I find keys with `83` and `75` but I am having trouble verifying their order.

Comment: Not only order is important, the values need to be right next to one another. Your second key has `'83'` followed by `'75'`. Do you need to search for *longer* keys too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple for loop will suffice. The `index` function will throw a `ValueError` if either `'83'` or `'75'` is not found. The Pythonic way to do this would be a try-except block.:

```
my_dict = {('22', '83', '75', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '22', '23', '24', '18', '14'): 1, 
           ('1', '2', '83', '5', '8', '75', '9', '12', '16', '17', '18', '14'): 1, 
           ('11', '2', '7', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '18', '14'): 1}
keys = []
for key in my_dict:
    try:
        if key.index('75') - key.index('83') == 1:
            keys.append(key)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

If you wanted to find keys that contain `75` after `83` no matter its proximity, you can use this version:

```
my_dict = {('22', '83', '75', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '22', '23', '24', '18', '14'): 1, 
           ('1', '2', '83', '5', '8', '75', '9', '12', '16', '17', '18', '14'): 1, 
           ('11', '2', '7', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '18', '14'): 1}
keys = []
for key in my_dict:
    try:
        if '75' in key[key.index('83'):]:
            keys.append(key)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: OP asked for them consecutively this will add any they have a `75` after the `83`

Comment: What if the key is longer?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you explain what you mean with 'if the key is longer'?

Comment: What if the OP wanted to find `(83, 75, 5)` or `(83, 75, 5, 8)`?

Comment: The OP explicitly did not want to support your second option; the second key should not match, but your second option does match it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand that my second example doesn't quite fit the OP's question. However, just like your 'longer keys' modification, my second example is decent example of a possible change in specification. As for how I would answer your longer keys modification, I would use the same kind of solution as [enx does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24168448/3661996).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can check if the first item in your tuple is in any of the keys and, once found, use tuple slicing and `len(query)` to retrieve the next indices and check their equality. Try this, although I have not tested it.

```
query = ('83', '75')
mydict = {('22', '83', '75', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '22', '23', '24', '18', '14'): 1, 
 ('1', '2', '83', '5', '8', '75', '9', '12', '16', '17', '18', '14'): 1, 
 ('11', '2', '7', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '18', '14'): 1}

for k in mydict:
    try:
        i = k.index(query[0])
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        if k[i:i+len(query)] == query:
            return k, '->', mydict[k]
```

Comment: This at least supports searches for longer tuples. **Note**: the OP input query contains integers, the keys are tuples of *strings*, so your code won't match anything. The approach is sound, however.

Comment: Oops, right. I fixed the query. I guess the OP also missed that, but if not, `map` and `str` could come in handy!

Answer (score 1):

Please use the index method of tuple

For example, for the first key tuple {('22', '83', '75', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '22', '23', '24', '18', '14')

```
>>> a = ('22', '83', '75', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '22', '23', '24', '18', '14')
>>> a.index("83")
1
>>> a.index("75")
2
```

Together, the condition expression would be:

```
>>> "83" in a and "75" in a and a.index("83") == a.index("75") - 1
True
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please teach my why it is not useful here? The poster asked "I am having trouble verifying their order." The index method works good here.

Comment: @Sheng You were simply throwing your initial answer too quickly, for that the comment of Martijn definitely applied. Now it looks much better.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky I know the initial answer is short and simple. But it shows the very key to the solution. If short is wrong, the forum should hold a stricter word count check before posting. Anyway, I will pay my attention not to post a short one.

Comment: @Sheng: Your FGITW answer was **far** from complete. Only your most recent edit makes it an actual answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks to your reminder. I will follow the style.

Comment: Note that your answer is not correct yet; the OP wants to match a proper subsequence, not a longest common subsequence; it is not the order that is important but that the key is matched only when the elements are directly consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find that 83 exists, but 75 does not, then it obviously does not exist as a pair.  If both exist, then you could test to see if the index of 83 and 75 have a difference equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator-based solution might be handy here

```
sentinel = object()
for k in d:
    i = iter(k)
    if '83' in i and next(i, sentinel) == '75':
        print k

('22', '83', '75', '5', '8', '7', '9', '12', '16', '17', '22', '23', '24', '18', '14')
```